# How do I get rid of extra debug information inside IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

I am getting way too much debugging information inside IntelliJ and am not sure how to get rid of it??? This is for a ruby+rails application.

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta14, ruby-debug-base 0.11.30.pre10) listens on 127.0.0.1:12685
Connected from 127.0.0.1
11247: Starting control thread
11247: Processing in control: b /Users/kamilski81/Sites/sc/config/initializers/mongoid.rb:9
11247: <breakpointAdded no="1" location="/Users/kamilski81/Sites/sc/config/initializers/mongoid.rb:9"/>
11247: Processing in control: b /Users/kamilski81/Sites/sc/config/initializers/mongoid.rb:2
11247: <breakpointAdded no="2" location="/Users/kamilski81/Sites/sc/config/initializers/mongoid.rb:2"/>
11247: Processing in control: b /Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@sc/gems/rails_admin-0.0.5/lib/rails_admin/config/model.rb:27
11247: <breakpointAdded no="3" location="/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@sc/gems/rails_admin-0.0.5/lib/rails_admin/config/model.rb:27"/>
11247: Processing in control: b /Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@sc/gems/rails_admin-0.0.5/lib/rails_admin/config.rb:240
11247: <breakpointAdded no="4" location="/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@sc/gems/rails_admin-0.0.5/lib/rails_admin/config.rb:240"/>
11247: Processing in control: b /Users/kamilski81/Sites/sc/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:52
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA and RubyMine doesn't do it by default, most likely the output with `print_debug` method occurs because `Debugger.cli_debug=true` is present somewhere in your code or you have `RUBYMINE_DEBUG_VERBOSE` environment variable set to `true`, or this option was enabled:

[image: verbose debugger output]

(IntelliJ IDEA has the same setting)